# Kubernetes: prevent pods from communicating with the node-ips

Tags: kubernetes, firewall, k3s, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a Kubernetes cluster running behind a NAT. Now I want to forbid the pods to communicate with the network in which my Kubernetes nodes / servers are. The network has the CIRD: `10.12.12.0/27`.

I've already tried the Kubernetes NetworkPolicy, but I haven't figured out how to prohibit communication with certain IPs. Instead, I have limited the Konnunikation to these IP's.
Here is my previous NetworkPolicy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: block-net-kubernetes
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      namespace: default
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.12.12.0/27
```

Many thanks in advance!
Kind regards Niclas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expect` block to filter out some IPs.  Using that, the below example is allowing all egress but blocking traffic to `10.12.12.0/27`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: block-net-kubernetes
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      namespace: default
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
            except:
              - 10.12.12.0/27
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to P....! It works! But there is an litte formatting error: The `except:` statement needs to be indented one more.
Like here:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: block-net-kubernetes
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      namespace: default
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
            except:
              - 10.12.12.0/27
```